# How to make python 3.5.2 application exe?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have tried so many ways to make a python 3.5.2 application executable (a standalone `exe`) but didn't work. I tried the `py installer` and `py to exe` but it didn't work.

How can I make an `exe` in Python 3.5.2?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? What is the error msg? Have you installed pyinstaller with pip? Have you tried to create the exe with the command " pyinstaller --onefile [your script].py "?

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: It gave me a fatal error and says couldn't execute" file name "

Comment: Actually it make exe file but exe file doesnt work

Comment: Type error = a bytes-like objects is required , not ' str'

Comment: this is the error comes in the middle of processing and it pass from this error and give me in the end exe file and path. but the file is not open when you click on it and it says fatal error

Comment: I have the impression that the error is not related to pyinstaller, do you get the same error when you execute your Python script or only when you try to make the exe? If it's a test script, can you update your question with the code?

Comment: This error happen just whenever i want to make an exe file in cmd or powershell with pyinstaller

Comment: The code I am using is :

Comment: pyinstaller  –onedir  --onefile –name=fighter1 –windowed
“C:\users\AB\Google Drive\Computer Programing\1-Python\Applications\file.py”

Comment: I did not have any error such that in python so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe what you're looking for is Python Portable. It allows you to run Python from a memory stick without having to install it. However, you REALLY need to clean up your question.

Py2Exe is for converting programs written in python into standalone executables, not for making Python Portable.

http://portablepython.com/wiki/Download/

Comment: definitely I will try Python Portable too.\